# <AgGridColumn> component vs columnDefs prop in AgGridReact

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

What is the difference between using the `<AgGridColumn>` component and passing `columnDefs` prop to `<AgGridReact>`

```
<AgGridReact
 rowData={rowData}
>
 <AgGridColumn field="make"></AgGridColumn>
 <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
 <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
</AgGridReact>
```

vs

```
<AgGridReact
 rowData={rowData}
 columnDefs={[{field: "make"},{field: "model"},{field: "price"}]}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<AgGridColumn>` was introduced in v24 to allow creating column definitions declaratively  for React resulting in application code that fits more nicely with the React paradigm.

Relevant documentation:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-definitions/#declarative-columns

Comment: is the `columnDefs` prop not declarative?

Comment: <AgGridColumn> was introduced for users of React (functional components) but using columnDefs is also fine. Either way, both work exactly the same way, it's purely a matter of preference.